# Custom session another class

Tags: android, session, exception, sharedpreferences, stack-overflow

I tried make my custom session, but I have a normal problem, but I don't see the error :

In my class Main :

```
session.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also in my Class session have :

```
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String mypreferences2, int modePrivate){
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreferences2,
            modePrivate);
    return this.sharedpreferences;
}
```

And I get, why ?

```
03-12 00:22:09.104: E/AndroidRuntime(7595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 00:22:09.104: E/AndroidRuntime(7595): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-12 00:22:09.104: E/AndroidRuntime(7595):     at com.example.support.Session.getSharedPreferences(Session.java:41)
03-12 00:22:09.104: E/AndroidRuntime(7595):     at com.example.support.Session.getSharedPreferences(Session.java:41)
03-12 00:22:09.104: E/AndroidRuntime(7595):     at com.example.support.Session.getSharedPreferences(Session.java:41)
03-12 00:22:09.104: E/AndroidRuntime(7595):     at com.example.support.Session.getSharedPreferences(Session.java:41)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a `StackOverflowError` is because your method is recursively calling itself ad infinitum. If your class `Main` is a subclass of `Activity`, you merely need to call:

```
this.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If, indeed, you do need information from Shared Preferences in another class, it would be advisable to retrieve it in your `Activity` and then pass the info to the class through a constructor, a public method, etc.